# Saving a float value in a certain moment in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I did the Brackeys Tutorial and I am trying to make my own game off of it and the first thing i wanted to do was a restart screen and for that i need the score but if the cube falls off it still goes forward so i need the z value of the cube when it falls of the edge

Comment: Sounds like a great time to use a collision trigger on an invisible rectangle below your terrain.

Comment: can you explain it to me?

Comment: You can put a collider on a object with no visible mesh and then use methods such as [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) to capture data about objects that collide with it. I recommend checking out the plethora of tutorials around regarding using collision triggers to perform actions exactly like you want (performing a scripted action when a object enters a certain area).

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: What is `the Brackeys Tutorial` and what exactly are you talking about ? Please have in mind that here on StackOverflow we don't have your project in front of us and we don't know what video/tutorial you are following ....

Comment: brackeys is a youtube channel and he did a tutorial on how to make a video game and i did the tutorial and now im trying to make my own game off of it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

If you just want to save the float value of a transform, use something like

float z = cube.transform.position.z;

When setting the transform, you need to use a whole Vector3; you can't just change one value.

cube.transform.position = Vector3(cube.transform.position.x, cube.transform.position.y, z);

Ok. According to your comment,

```
bool checkForY = true;

GameObject cube;

float cubeZ;

void Update()
{
    if (checkForY)
    {
       if (cube.transform.position.y < 0)
       {
          cubeZ = cube.transform.position.z;
          checkForY = false;
       }
    }
}
```

This should work. You might want to rename "cubeZ" to whatever you're using it for, though.

Comment: I want to save the z value when the cubes y value is under 0

Comment: I've edited the thing.